# Dell XPS13 9333 - Big trouble updating Ubuntu to 15.10

Tags: upgrade, 15.10, dell, xps

a few days ago I had the unfortunate idea to upgrade my well-working Ubuntu 14.04 to 15.10 simply running the software update manager.
Result: the installation went worng and now my Dell XPS13 9333 is unusable, because is extremely slow, touchpad and mouse are not working anymore and even it can't connect to the wireless network to run any command to try a repair of the system.

Please, might anybody help me on trying to reverse the installation to 14.04 or repair the 15.10 one?
You will save my life! I need to get back my laptop for my job.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Lorenz

Answer (score 0):

What is `sudo apt-get -f install` giving you? Can you repair the botched upgrade with it? If not, your best option is to move forward with `update-manager` to xenial now. My Dell XPS12-9Q33 on which I am typing right now is fully supported.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply emk2203!

I'm going to follow your suggestion and try to fix it as well.
I'll come back with a feedback as soon as possible to share the result.

Lorenz

Comment: If you don't have a special reason, it's better to skip the in-between versions between LTS versions if a LTS is available. They don't get much love and are supported only for a short time.

16.04 is really stable and gives little trouble, I run it on 6 systems (5 desktops, 1 server) since Nov 2015. A small group of people have issues with the graphics initialization, but it usually works, and more problem-free than 14.04 ever was for me.

Comment: Thank you again emk2203, but I chose a simpler way.
After arguing with my lapton trying (unsuccessfully) to boot it with the external dvd drive, I decided to run the boot tapping the shift key and executed the recovery mode to get access to command line.
Then I copied my user folder into an external hard disk and then restored my laptop to factory 12.04.
After that I updated all the packages and then upgraded to 14.04.
Now I'll wait this summer when the release 16.04.01 will be notified to me via upgrade manager.

Thanks anyway for you help and suggestions.
I apreciated them very much.

Lorenz